# Getting openmp to create more than one thread

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, openmp

Every time I try to print out the `threadID`, and regardless of where I put the print statement, it always prints the `threadId = 0`. It looks like there is only one thread being created, but why? I don't see what I'm doing wrong. Also, I've checked and `num_t = 16`. I've also made sure that I use `-fopenmp` when compiling.

```
omp_set_num_threads(num_t);
#pragma omp parallel shared(a,b,c) private(i,j,k) num_threads(num_t)
{

    #pragma omp for schedule(static)
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        std::cout << omp_get_thread_num()<< "\n";
        for (int j = 0; (j < n); j++)
        {
            c[i + j*m] = 0.0;
            for (int k = 0; k < q; k++)
            {
                c[i+j*m] +=  a[i*q + k]*b[j*q + k];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at the compiler warnings (e.g. with `-Wall`)? Is your pragma statment being ignored? Why do you have a backslash before the pragma (`\#pragma`)? What's the size of `m`?

Answer (score 0):

To test first, I recommend you to use this:

```
#pragma omp parallel for private(...) shared(...) schedule(...) num_threads (X)
```

where "X" is the number of threads to be created. In theory, the previous line must have a similar effect to yours, but C++ can be picky sometimes (specially with the "parallel" clause)

Btw, maybe is not your case, but be careful using "text keys" {}. OpenMP's functionality can be different depending on adding them to the code block or not.

Comment: What do you mean by "text keys". The extra brackets are there because this is inside of a function. So there is some other outside of the brackets.